# SharePoint 2016 Distributed Cache Service won't Start on Single-Server Farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, distributedcache, health-analyzer

I have a single server farm running SharePoint 2016.

1. Under Health Analyzer: Distributed cache service is not configured on server.  I ran add-spdistributedcacheserviceinstance, reanalyzed and same error.
2. Under Health Analyzer: Server Role configuration isn't correct.  I clicked repair automatically, reanalyzed and same error.

I went to Manage Services on Server and Distributed Cache compliant is No.  I manually clicked start for the service and it doesn't start.  Clicking fix does nothing.  The AppFabric Caching Service under services some is set to disabled.  I enable under services, repeated steps and same issue. Get-CacheHost shows AppFabric Caching Service "UP."

How can I get this service started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by running the following commands:

1. remove-spdistributedcacheserviceinstance
2. add-spdistributedcacheserviceinstance